# GCP API Gateway JWT always returning 403

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jwt, swagger, api-gateway

I'm using gcp api gateway for JWT authentication. after generating a token from my auth service and then putting it in postman I always receive this response no matter what I put in the 'aud' part of the token:

[image]

Here is my open api file:

```
# openapi2-run.yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: my-gateway-id
  description: Sample API on API Gateway with a Cloud Run backend
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
x-google-backend:
  address: https://my-cloud-run.a.run.app
  jwt_audience: https://my-cloud-run.a.run.app
securityDefinitions:
  jwt_auth:
    authorizationUrl: ''
    flow: 'implicit'
    type: 'oauth2'
    x-google-issuer: 'id-admin@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
    x-google-jwks_uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/id-admin@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
paths:
  /:
    post:
      security:
        - jwt_auth: []
      summary: GraphQL endpoint
      operationId: gql
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: object
```

I've looked over and over the docs and can't see what's going on? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get 403 because the `aud` on the JWT token you've generated is not found on **securityDefinitions** of your API config.

> To allow additional client IDs to access the backend service, you can specify the allowed client IDs in the `x-google-audiences` field by using comma-separated values. API Gateway then accepts the JWTs with any of the specified client IDs in the aud claim.

Go [here](https://jwt.io/) and paste your token to see your JWT "aud" claim. If you generated the ID token using `gcloud auth`, the aud will most likely be a Client ID like `1234567890.apps.googleusercontent.com`. But if you generated the token using your own service, then it would depend on what you've specified as a target audience.

To solve the problem, add `x-google-audiences` field on the **securityDefinitions** section and the value should match with your JWT "aud" claim.

Assuming that the `aud` on your JWT token is a Cloud Run service endpoint, then your API config should look like this. Feel free to check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-jwt#configuring_apig_to_support_client_authentication) as additional reference:

```
x-google-backend:
  address: https://my-cloud-run.a.run.app 
securityDefinitions:
  jwt_auth:
    authorizationUrl: ''
    flow: 'implicit'
    type: 'oauth2'
    x-google-issuer: 'id-admin@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
    x-google-jwks_uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/id-admin@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
    x-google-audiences: 'https://my-cloud-run.a.run.app'
```

If you have [multiple](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#x-google-audiences) audiences, then it should be a single string separated by a comma. Spaces aren't allowed between the audiences.